# Restoring icloud data to app

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

In my app i sync my data to iCloud successfully, Even i can see that file iCloud settings. But now i dont know how get that file back from iCloud to my app.

[image]

Please help me how get that file back

Comment: ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                   URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    
    NSURL *file = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents" isDirectory:true] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename"];

Comment: @CaptainRedmuff some where i had found this and tried but its not working

Answer (score 1):

The document already exists where you want it. You just need to do the right thing to access it. Use the URL that you get from your code, but don't include the last part with @"filename."

Pass the url to this method on the file manager:

- (NSArray *)contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:(NSURL *)url includingPropertiesForKeys:(NSArray *)keys options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions)mask error:(NSError **)error

The NSArray contains NSURL objects which point to the files and folders in that directory. Use the URL of the file that you want and open it as appropriate. For more info, see the NSFileManager documentation.

Comment: **NSURL * ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    // NSURL * ubiquitousPackage = [ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:DairiesListFilePath];
    NSURL * ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]  URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.csv"];** 

    


using these url i am trying to get back those files

Comment: There's no need to create those URLs manually, though. If you use the method I listed then it will give you an array of all the URLs you need. Or am I misunderstanding something?